# How to display divs with checkboxes logic?

Tags: jquery

I have form with 3 questions in divs (#q1, #q2, #q3). Each question consists of title and 3 answers in checkbox list.

I need to create the following:

1) if user checks the first answer (A1) in the first question (#q1), the question 2 (#q2) should disappears, question 3 (#q3) should appears, AND checkboxes for A2 and A3 should become unchecked,

2) if user checks the second and/or the third answers (A2 and/or A3) in the first question (#q1), the question 2 (#q2) should appears, question 3 (#q3) should disappears AND checkbox for A1 should become unchecked,

3) if user checks any answer in #q2 the #q3 should appears.

4) if user checks any answer in #q3 the submit button should appears.

I realize all except 2) - user cannot checks A2 or A3 if A1 is checked. How can I fix this problem?

```
index.html:

<div id="test">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <fieldset id="q1">
            <legend>Question1</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="A1" id="q1_1">
            <label for="q1_1">A1</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="A2" id="q1_2">
            <label for="q1_2">A2</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" value="A3" id="q1_3">
            <label for="q1_3">A3</label><br>
            <br>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="q2">
            <legend>Question2 - should appear if A2 or A3 is checked</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pe" value="B1" id="q2_1">
            <label for="q2_1">B1</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pe" value="B2" id="q2_2">
            <label for="q2_2">B2</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pe" value="B3" id="q2_3">
            <label for="q2_3">B3</label><br>
            <br>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="q3">
            <legend>Question3 - should appear if A1 is checked</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_p" value="C1" id="q3_1">
            <label for="q3_1">C1</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_p" value="C2" id="q3_2">
            <label for="q3_2">C2</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_p" value="C3" id="q3_3">
            <label for="q3_3">C3</label><br>
            <br>
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

script.js:

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#q2').addClass('hide');
$('#q3').addClass('hide');
$('#submit').addClass('hide');

$('#q1').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#q1 input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
        if ($('#q1_1').is(':checked')) {
            $('#q1_2').prop('checked', false);
            $('#q1_3').prop('checked', false);
            $('#q2').addClass('hide');
            $('#q3').removeClass('hide');
        }
        if ( $('#q1_2').is(':checked') || $('#q1_3').is(':checked') ) {
            $('#q1_1').prop('checked', false);
            $('#q2').removeClass('hide');

        }

    } else {
        $('#q2').addClass('hide');
        $('#q3').addClass('hide');
        $('#q2 input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
        $('#q3 input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
        $('#submit').addClass('hide');
    }


});

$('#q2').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#q2 input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
        $('#q3').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#q3').addClass('hide');
        $('#q3 input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
        $('#submit').addClass('hide');

    }
});

$('#q3').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#q3 input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
        $('#submit').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#submit').addClass('hide');

    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you only need the .hide() method for jQuery

```
 $('#q2').addClass('hide');
```

would be

```
 $('#q2').hide();
```

this is the same with .show() - very useful methods!

I think I've fixed Problem 2 here. It'll need some refactoring but they're the conditionals missing:

https://jsfiddle.net/t0y3xqdg/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But when I check A2 of A3 I cannot check A1.

Comment: Ah you didn't put that above, only the other way around. A1 cannot be checked at the same time as A2 & A3, correct? But you want a user to be able to change their mind and switch back to A1 from A2, and therefore remove Question 2?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for didn't specify it in my question.